# Reporting Services Home Page

Tags: reporting-services

I'm new on this product, I was able to install and configure reporting services for SQL Server 2014, I have two questions:

1. SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher is only available for SQL 2016?
2. When I create a A new report server project from VS 2017, I was able to configure everything and my report works fine but how can I create a friendly home page for the client to manage the different reports? because browsing the directory file is not very elegant :)

Comment: 1. Yes. The second question is very broad. You can go a sharepoint'esque route or If you don't mind developing a custom web app, look into the SSRS management and rendering api's.

Comment: There is a friendly home page... `http://MyServerName/Reports`

Comment: Do you know any tutorial for creating a website and relate it to reporting services?

Comment: Tutorial, no....
but guidance, yes....
You are going to need to use Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForm v14.0........and ReportingServices2010, hook those 2 up to your SSRS server and you can create a view of your SSRS.......(I just finished creating the exact same project)

Comment: ok thank you for your help